# Is there a way to show the iPhone skin with the lastest iOS 8 Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode-simulator

Previous versions of the iOS Simulator (7 and below) would also show the iPhone skin, which made for better demos:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with the iOS 8 Simulator? This isn't as compelling:

[image]

Comment: Do you run a Retina Macbook Pro or a 4K Monitor?

Comment: Yes, I run a 15" Retina Macbook Pro

Comment: For what it's worth, there's Loren Brichter's [SimFinger](https://github.com/atebits/SimFinger) ([more info](http://web.archive.org/web/20111207183520/http://blog.atebits.com/2009/03/not-your-average-iphone-screencast)), but I won't post that as an answer because it doesn't currently have iPhone 6 or 6 Plus graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's no longer possible. The recommended way for making demos is now using Quicktime in OS X Yosemite recorded directly from the device. If you wanted you could take that video and during post-production use one of the [App Store Marketing Templates](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images) to make it look a little nicer.

Comment: I should have clarified live screen-sharing demos, but this answers the direct question, though a disappointing change. Thanks.